# What 's the upper limit of a binomial expansion with fractional power?

Tags: calculus, binomial-coefficients

It's known that a binomial expansion can be writen as a sum,

$\displaystyle (a+b)^n=\binom{n}{0}a^n+ \binom{n}{1} a^{n-1}b+\binom{n}{2}a^{n-2}b^2+.....$

If the power, $n$, is a natural number, the last term of this sum will be $\displaystyle \binom{n}{n}b^n$, and so
$$ \displaystyle (a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}\cdot b^k$$

But, if the power is a rational positive number?

For instance,

$(1+x)^{\frac{1}{3}}=1+ \frac{1}{3}x+\frac{1}{3}(-\frac{2}{3})\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{1}{3}(-\frac{2}{3})(-\frac{5}{3})\frac{x^3}{3!}+......$

How far can I go with this sum?

Comment: You can go very far :) it's actually a Taylor expansion, so it has infinitely many terms. Do you have an underlying question coming with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you have to keep this in mind that the fractional powers can only be expanded if $|x|<1$. Now as $x^k\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$ so the terms become very smaller and smaller as you go high. You can expand it till anywhere but as the terms become small after a few stage there is no *noticeable* change in the value of the expression if we stop it after a certain stage.

Comment: Why does the  fractional powers can only be expanded if $|x|<1$?

Comment: It doesn't mean the fraction powers *can't be expanded*. Binomial theorem for a rational index follows from the Taylor's theorem and the remainder term of the Taylor series only converges when $|x|<1$. Which explains the part the left side is a finite quantity while the right side doesn't.

Comment: As otherwise it doesnot converge so there is no meaning to that expansion.Note that we are expanding means that the binomial converges and we are representing it as a series.

Comment: @Abhra Abir Kundu, I see it. A binomial expansion can be writen as $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k$. And this is a geometric series, where the ratio is $x$. So if $|x|\leq1$, the series will converge.